# Recommended HTML editor

Tags: html, css, html-editor

Is there another editor for HTML (and CSS) except Notepad++ which you can recommend?

In Notepad I miss the feature that if I write the 'p' tag for example, it won't be completed automatically to the 'p' tag with the slash. This is a disadvantage for quite long HTML scripts, since you might overlook something easily. The error search would have been more tedious.

Comment: Have you done any research on this, such as asking the bingleduck about "free html editor windows"? If so, what products have you looked at, what features do you need that they lack, what deficiencies do they have, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

I am using [Webuilder](https://www.webuilderapp.com/) for my IDE.  Its very reasonable and supports PHP, HTML, CSS, JS etc. It has autocompletions and colour syntax.  And you can run the html page from within, or launch the browser running your page.

[image]

---

They also have [HtmlPad](https://www.htmlpad.net/) which is more lightweight and only does html, css and js and is cheaper.

> **Intelligent HTML, CSS, JavaScript editor**
> HTML5 editor + CSS3 editor + JS editor
> HTMLPad is an intelligent all-in-one HTML, CSS and JavaScript code editor that will help you code faster and become more productive. Packed with powerful features and tools, HTMLPad enables you to create, edit, validate, reuse, navigate and deploy your HTML, CSS and JavaScript code quickly and easily.
>
> HTMLPad includes full-blown CSS studio and a powerful JavaScript editor offering you a complete package.

---

I am not associated with them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your tip. I will have a look at this recommendation indeed. It really seems to be the software I was really looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Visual Studio Code

Visual Studio Code, also commonly referred to as VS Code, is a source-code editor made by Microsoft with the Electron Framework, for Windows, Linux and macOS. Features include support for debugging, syntax highlighting, intelligent code completion, snippets, code refactoring, and embedded Git. --From Wikipedia

It has some really helpful features like intellisense, built in git commands, huge numbers of extensions and a lot of other custmozation options.